# Fade out on click, unless input element is clicked on

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, event-handling

The `.container` needs to fade out when the user clicks anywhere, but **not** when the user clicks in the input field.

Is there a way to make it fade out, unless the input field is clicked?

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tmyie/LtNhK/1/)

```js
$('.container').click(function () {
    $(this).fadeOut();
});
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aperiam eum ad adipisci velit assumenda cupiditate molestias facere officia neque maxime voluptatum officiis libero animi sit a accusamus culpa quasi quis!</p>
    <input type="text" name="" id="" autofocus />
</div>
```

**Bonus points if it works on older browsers.**

Comment: Answers given work but add more code than necessary. There is way to do this by checking that `e.target` (the element that is clicked on) is not the input field within the one anonymous function you already have.

Answer (score 5):

You need to stopevent propogating to textbox.
Use this:

```
$(".container input").click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
})
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LtNhK/2/)**

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[e.stopPropagation()](http://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/)** to prevent click event to buble up when your input getting focus:

```
$('.container input').click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();

});
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LtNhK/4/)**

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$(".container input").click(function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answers use `stopPropagation`, but it also works with `return false;`

```
$('.container input').click(function() {
   return false;
});
$('.container').click(function () {
  $(this).fadeOut();
});
```

Comment: That article points out what `return false` is actually doing: "`event.preventDefault();`
`event.stopPropagation();` and 
`Stops callback execution and returns immediately when called.`"  Which works and is appropriate in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

wow..so many answers....try this one too...just use `$(event.target)` to find what was clicked on the `body` element and if its not the input, then `toggle` the container!! :)

[**solution fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/LtNhK/5/)

```
$('body').click(function(event) {
    if($(event.target).is('#input'))
    {}
    else
    {
        $('.container').toggle(1200);
    }

});
```

and add an `id`  to `<input type="text" name="" id="input" autofocus />`

if not then , ammned to

```
if($(event.target).is('input'))      
                   /* ^^ removed # tag from here*/
```

[**demo without an id to input element**](http://jsfiddle.net/LtNhK/6/)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a way, see demo below.

```
$('.container').click(function (e) {
  if ($(e.target).closest("input[type='text']").length === 0) {
      $(this).fadeOut();
  }
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jakethejab/kwUML/5/)

Comment: This is close to what I mean but it can still be done with fewer characters

Answer (score -1):

Or

```
$('.container').not('input').click(function () {...});
```

There are many posts like this...

Comment: Thank you, forgot the dot :-(

Comment: and the closing `);`
=)

Comment: This will not work. Clicking the input will bubble up to .container

Comment: And the semicolon, but we suppose tmyie knows his own code lol